# Angular dynamic form groups with dynamic design

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 7 app.
In this app I am using reactive forms with nested form fields (formArray). I can, by the click of a button, add new formArray items (and remove them). What I need to do is to display different UI elements depending of a value of an input field. The reason for this is that I want to let the user add different form groups depending on the type of question element they want to add (I am building a survey app).

No matter what question type they are using it is using the same form fields but with different designs.

When I add a group I attach this:

```
initItem(type) {
    return this._fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      otype: [type],
      duration: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Otype is the type of question design. How can I use this otype value to transform the design of the question form group? For example hiding some part of showing another?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: It seems like best solution would be to create component that have some kind of dictionary with changing designs. Same with that you can create an array with from group and otype properties, and pass them to component in ngFor loop to acheve that.

Comment: why not bind this property to the template and use there *ngIf for your differnet controls?

Comment: @RenéWinkler how can I bind the property to a template? I agree this is a good way but I don´t know how to do it.